# Odd AC_RunActiveContent.js requirement 

Tags: windows, flash, windows-7, embed

I am having an odd issue with attempting to embed a dcr file.  When embedded using a simple embed code it works fine on **my** Window 7 OS system using IE 8 it works fine.

However on another laptop with the same OS and browser it only works if i inject the embed code to the DOM by using AC_RunActiveContent.js like bellow.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<script src="ac_run_active_content.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="ac_flash.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
<script language="javascript"> 

AC_RunSWContent(
        'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/director/sw.cab#version=11,5,9,620',
        'src', '01140-01',
        'wmode','opaque',
        'id', 'sw',
        'name', 'welcome',
        'width', '468',
        'height', '268',
        'swremote', "swSaveEnabled='false' swVolume='false' swRestart='false' swPausePlay='false' swFastForward='false' swContextMenu='true'",
        'swstretchstyle', 'none',
        'bgcolor', '#ffffff',
        'playerVersion','11',
        'sw1','11.5.9',
        'sw2','620'
        );

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

The obvious solution is that I just change the source, however the main issue is that there are thousands of files that are showing the same problems on this particular computer, and it would take an army to hunt them all down and change them.  Any ideas? I am totally stumped.

**Additionally:**  The computers that are giving the problem are secured laptops, so in the process of it failing on the simple Object tag method, I get a message: "The requested operation requires elevation". This tells me that the player is calling an application in the harddrive, and is being flagged as a risk (Sales people can't be given admin privileges).  This brings me to ask, why does this happen on the Object embed method and not the javascript method?